# willRotateToInterfaceOrientation not being called in a modally presented view controller

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios6, uiinterfaceorientation, screen-rotation

My whole app is portrait. When you tap an image in a collection view controller, I present the images in a MWPhotoBrowser View Controller modally. So I want to support multiple orientations there. I'm only supporting iOS 6, and have the following orientation methods:

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotate {
    return YES;
}


- (NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations {
    return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskAllButUpsideDown;
}
```

These get called, but `willRotateToInterfaceOrientation` and subsequent `willAnimateRotationToInterfaceOrientation` and `didRotateFromInterfaceOrientation` are never called.

It isn't presented in a navigation controller or anything. Not sure what else I need to do here to have rotation supported ONLY in the modally presented view controller.

Answer (score 2):

After re-reading documentation, I believe my app has to support landscape orientations at the application (plist) level. In that case, I will have to change the supported orientations in my other view controllers to restrict it I guess.